# How to solve "Updating failed" with 403 Error when trying to save a Site or Post in Gutenberg?

Tags: ajax, errors, server

When I try to save my site in the Gutenberg Editor it just says "Updating failed".

How to fix that?

Comment: Is there more information in your browsers dev tools? Look under the console for any JS errors or warnings

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons this error can occur. Those two were the most frequent for me:

### Session-Cookie

Open the Javascript Console by pressing F12 and click on the tab "Console". If you see some error message that goes something like `cookie_nonce` it's a session cookie problem.

The problem solves by just completely logging out and possibly also deleting all cookies of your website.

### File-Permissions

If you have a webserver you manage on your own it may be that file permissions are wrong.

The [instructions here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46331/how-to-avoid-using-sudo-when-working-in-var-www) have never failed to resolve my issues so far, so it's worth checking out.

It's those commands:

Add yourself to www-data group:

```
sudo gpasswd -a "$USER" www-data
```

Change file permissions:

```
sudo chown -R "$USER":www-data /var/www
find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 0660 {} \;
sudo find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 2770 {} \;
```

Comment: These shouldn't be issues, I'd raise them on the github repo or the core WP trac

Comment: @TomJNowell I admit my own server installation is a bit "dirty" the second cause would probably not happen on a professional hosting service.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact issue with a client site with GoDaddy. Clearing browser and site cache or disabling plugins wouldn't work either. 
The only workaround was to `login and work from an incognito window`. 
In a normal Chrome window it only seemed to work like 1 in 10 times.

**In incognito it works normally without any issue.**

So I'm assuming there should be something going on with browser configurations or extensions. Not a definite solution but I'm just putting this workaround here for anybody else pulling their hair because of this problem.

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem: on a specific computer, I'm getting 403 constantly, but it works on another computer without any problem.